# Extract Equation from Latex in Python

Tags: python, latex

I want to extract an equation from a Latex file in python.

```
import re
with open('file.tex',encoding='utf-8') as f: data = f.read()
pattern= r'\\begin\{equation*\}(.*?)\\end\{equation*\}'
re.findall(pattern, data, re.S)
```

however the output remains empty.(I have also tried with re.DOTALL, it does not work)
I have tried also using the tex2py library https://github.com/alvinwan/tex2py/
but so far I can only get text, and not equations. In the end I want to print them to my streamlit frontend via st.markdown/st.latex.
Doas anyone have an idea?

Comment: You likely need to escape the `*` in `equation*`, since that character has a special meaning in regex. (In fact, you know that, because you use it that way in `(.*?)`.)

Comment: Just a hint: if regexp is greedy as in Perl, assuming you have 10 equations in the file, you'll get the start of the first, anything inbetween until the end of the 10th ... which is probably not what you want.